# How to insert value from user defined datatypes to object in java?

Tags: java, types

I'm creating an object of type Lightmode, which is a class.
There's also a Smartlamp class which is having a variable of custom data of type Lighmodes and I want to show my defined data type value over there.
I'm trying to create an object and then insert a string against my Lightmode data type which is showing error. I want to print like this:
Name:  lamp1  
Location: 3.1  
Switched On:  false  
Mode:  STANDARD 
Here mode is lightmode datatype and I'm getting a problem over it.
...

```
public class LightModes
{
String NIGHT_MODE; 
String SOFT_MODE;
String STANDARD_MODE;

public String getNIGHT_MODE() {
return NIGHT_MODE;
}

public void setNIGHT_MODE(String NIGHT_MODE) {
this.NIGHT_MODE = NIGHT_MODE;
}

public String getSOFT_MODE() {
return SOFT_MODE;
}

public void setSOFT_MODE(String SOFT_MODE) {
this.SOFT_MODE = SOFT_MODE;
}

public String getSTANDARD_MODE() {
return STANDARD_MODE;
}

public void setSTANDARD_MODE(String STANDARD_MODE) {
this.STANDARD_MODE = STANDARD_MODE;
}

public LightModes() {
this.NIGHT_MODE = "NIGHT";
this.STANDARD_MODE = "STANDARD";
this.SOFT_MODE = "SOFT";
}



}...

...package smart.home.app;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Step5 {
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
int size,mode;
int displayindex=1;
String name;
double location,temperature;
boolean status=false;
System.out.println("Enter number of size of Fridge you want to add.");
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
size=in.nextInt();
// TODO code application logic here
SmartLamp[] smartLamp=new SmartLamp[size];// creating an array object of smartdevice class

//       
for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
{

System.out.println("Enter Lamp name.");
name=input.readLine();
System.out.println("Enter Lamp Location.\\hint(1.1)");
Scanner devicelocation=new Scanner(System.in);
location=devicelocation.nextDouble();
System.out.println("Enter Lamp Mode.(1 for Night 2 for Soft 3 for Standard)");
Scanner lampmode=new Scanner(System.in);
mode=lampmode.nextInt();
System.out.println("Enter Lamp status.1 for ON, 0 for OFF.");
Scanner devicestatus=new Scanner(System.in);
int currentstatus=devicestatus.nextInt();
if(currentstatus==1)
{
status=true;
}
else if(currentstatus==0)
{
status=false;
}
LightModes light = null;
smartLamp[j]=new SmartLamp(light.NIGHT_MODE, name, location, status);

}


//////////////Display Data////////////////////////////
for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
{
System.out.println("-Smart lamp "+displayindex+" -");
System.out.println(smartLamp[i].toString()); 
System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
displayindex++;
}
}
}...



...public class SmartLamp extends SmartDevice{
private LightModes lightModes;

public LightModes getLightModes() {
return lightModes;
}

public void setLightModes(LightModes lightModes) {
this.lightModes = lightModes;
}
public SmartLamp(String name, double location, boolean switchedOn) {
super(name, location, switchedOn);
}

public SmartLamp(LightModes lightModes, String name, double location, boolean switchedOn) {
super(name, location, switchedOn);
this.lightModes = lightModes;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
return "SmartLamp{"+"\nName."+getName()+"\nLocation."
+getLocation() + "\nSwitchedOn."+isSwitchedOn()+
"\nMode=" + getLightModes() + '}';
}

}...
```

Comment: Are you getting error here: `LightModes light = null;
smartLamp[j]=new SmartLamp(light.NIGHT_MODE, name, location, status);`

Answer (score 0):

I downloaded your code and added the missing class `SmartDevice`. Your code contains two compiler errors.

1. `name = input.readLine();`
   This line throws `java.io.IOException` which is an unchecked exception and hence must be handled by your code. There are several ways to do this, one of which is to add `throws IOException` to method `main()` in class `Step5`.
2. `smartLamp[j]=new SmartLamp(light.NIGHT_MODE, name, location, status);`
   The first argument to `SmartLamp` constructor is an instance of class `LightModes` but you are passing a `String`. You need to create an instance of `LightModes`.

Here is your code with my modifications that get rid of the two compiler errors.
(Note: The below code includes my guessed implementation of class `SmartDevice`.)

```java
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Step5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException { // Change here.
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int size, mode;
        int displayindex = 1;
        String name;
        double location, temperature;
        boolean status = false;
        System.out.println("Enter number of size of Fridge you want to add.");
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        size = in.nextInt();
        SmartLamp[] smartLamp = new SmartLamp[size];// creating an array object of smartdevice class

        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
            System.out.println("Enter Lamp name.");
            name = input.readLine(); // throws java.io.IOException
            System.out.println("Enter Lamp Location.\\hint(1.1)");
            Scanner devicelocation = new Scanner(System.in);
            location = devicelocation.nextDouble();
            System.out.println("Enter Lamp Mode.(1 for Night 2 for Soft 3 for Standard)");
            Scanner lampmode = new Scanner(System.in);
            mode = lampmode.nextInt();
            System.out.println("Enter Lamp status.1 for ON, 0 for OFF.");
            Scanner devicestatus = new Scanner(System.in);
            int currentstatus = devicestatus.nextInt();
            if (currentstatus == 1) {
                status = true;
            }
            else if (currentstatus == 0) {
                status = false;
            }
            LightModes light = new LightModes(); // Change here.
            light.setNIGHT_MODE(light.getNIGHT_MODE()); // Change here.
            smartLamp[j] = new SmartLamp(light, name, location, status); // Change here.
        }

        //////////////Display Data////////////////////////////
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
        System.out.println("-Smart lamp "+displayindex+" -");
        System.out.println(smartLamp[i].toString()); 
        System.out.println("---------------------------------------------");
        displayindex++;
        }
    }
}

class LightModes {
    String NIGHT_MODE;
    String SOFT_MODE;
    String STANDARD_MODE;

    public String getNIGHT_MODE() {
        return NIGHT_MODE;
    }

    public void setNIGHT_MODE(String NIGHT_MODE) {
        this.NIGHT_MODE = NIGHT_MODE;
    }

    public String getSOFT_MODE() {
        return SOFT_MODE;
    }

    public void setSOFT_MODE(String SOFT_MODE) {
        this.SOFT_MODE = SOFT_MODE;
    }

    public String getSTANDARD_MODE() {
        return STANDARD_MODE;
    }

    public void setSTANDARD_MODE(String STANDARD_MODE) {
        this.STANDARD_MODE = STANDARD_MODE;
    }

    public LightModes() {
        this.NIGHT_MODE = "NIGHT";
        this.STANDARD_MODE = "STANDARD";
        this.SOFT_MODE = "SOFT";
    }
}

class SmartDevice {
    private String name;
    private double location;
    private boolean switchedOn;

    public SmartDevice(String name, double location, boolean switchedOn) {
        this.name = name;
        this.location = location;
        this.switchedOn = switchedOn;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public boolean isSwitchedOn() {
        return switchedOn;
    }
}

class SmartLamp extends SmartDevice {
    private LightModes lightModes;

    public LightModes getLightModes() {
        return lightModes;
    }

    public void setLightModes(LightModes lightModes) {
        this.lightModes = lightModes;
    }

    public SmartLamp(String name, double location, boolean switchedOn) {
        super(name, location, switchedOn);
    }

    public SmartLamp(LightModes lightModes, String name, double location, boolean switchedOn) {
        super(name, location, switchedOn);
        this.lightModes = lightModes;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "SmartLamp{" + "\nName." + getName() + "\nLocation." + getLocation()
                + "\nSwitchedOn." + isSwitchedOn() + "\nMode=" + getLightModes() + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer and it helps me a lot to understand some more concepts. I would love to discuss some things because I'm not getting any error now but there is some value problem because light mode giving garbage value instead of actual light mode string value.
Let me know how I can share code with you I mean email something???

Comment: Post another question.